# Ubuntu 20.04 starts with welcome screen every time, cannot login

Tags: login, users, 20.04, user-management

This started when I was trying to change my default shell to fish, which didn't work properly (might be of relevance here maybe?). I logged out through the menu on the upper right and couldn't log back in, was pretty scared I could have lost all my stuff but when I created another user and logged out from there, I was able to log back in to my main user.
However since then, every time I boot, it shows this welcome screen which takes me through the steps of creating a new user and I can't do anything unless I create another new user, log out from there and login to my main user. I tried deleting all of the new users but that doesn't help either.
Another hint: When I'm logged in to my main user, the settings app says "no users found"

So the thing with the shell change: I tried to switch to fish with the "chsh" command but it kept saying that I cannot change the shell for my user which, as far as I understand shouldn't be the case, I should be able to change my own default shell without sudo rights, right? Then I tried it with usermod -s, logged out and the chaos began :)

Every time I try to get into linux I really like it at first, and then something like this stops me which is such a shame.

Comment: Hi! @sirsimon771, I am facing the same issue. Try to shift from gdm3 to lightdm, it will solve the login problem. But the setting >> users>> no users found is unresolved.